# How to get next n lines from a file when a required line is found in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am trying going thorough a c++ file line by line and when a line is found I want to iterate over the next n (predetermined) line.

For instance,

if a file has the following structure:

```
..... some text
..... some text
..... some text
Area metrics:
5234 24345 6536543 6543543
5234 23645 6536564 6543543
5234 23245 6636343 6757280
Length Metrics:
1 20 3 4
63 55 22 45
6 7 28 56
..... some text
..... some text
```

I know how to check if a line begins with "Area Metrics" but I am not sure how to read line-by-line the next 4 lines (I already know how many lines I should be reading). I know how to do this in Python but it seems a bit more involved in C++. Any pointers on how to do this?

So far, I have this.

```
    for( std::string line = ""; getline( infile, line ); ){
        std::string comm_info("Area metrics");
        if( line.find(comm_info) == 0u){
           /* iterate over next 4 lines *?
        }
    }
```

This is my other solution. I am reading them into a vector of lines and comparing each one of them to my desired string. It works fine but it is not very elegant.

```
    std::string line;
    std::string comm_info("Area metrics");
    std::vector<std::string> myLines;
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        myLines.push_back(line);
    }
    for(auto it = myLines.begin(); it != myLines.end(); ++it) {
        if ((*it).find(comm_info) == 0u){
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
            std::cout  << *(it+i)<< "\n"; //Can replace with other things
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried something in C++? Can you share this code? This shouldn't be that hard

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I had added some more info. The text doesn't start with "Area Metrics" This occurs somewhere in the middle of a huge text file.

Comment: @drescherjm I added some more context to my problem.

Comment: How about a second for loop where you want to iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know about `std::getline()` to read a line from the file, so simply call it an additional `n` times when needed, eg:

```cpp
for (std::string line; getline(infile, line); ){
    if (line.compare(0, 13, "Area metrics:") == 0){
        std::string lines[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            std::getline(infile, lines[i]);
        }
        // use lines[] as needed...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using a different approach to solve it and I had included it in the question but I felt it was not very elegant. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you test the result of the second getline like you do with the first.

Answer (score -2):

Use a for loop to read in the next four lines like

```cpp
for(auto i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    // read in lines and process similar to how you processed that first line
}
```